# How to apt-delete-repository?

Tags: debian, apt

I would like to run the reverse of this command to remove the non-compatible repository in Debian 8.1

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:nemh/systemback
```

where the command `add-apt-repository` is in the package `software-properties-common`. 
I could not find the `systemback` entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

How can you run the reverse of the command?

Answer (score 282, accepted):

To remove a repository, you have to do two things:

- Remove it from `sources.list`.

  If it was added by `add-apt-repository` then you will find it in its own file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, not in the main `sources.list`.

  ```
   sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nemh-systemback-precise.list
  ```
- Optional: Stop trusting the key

  Use `apt-key list` to list trusted keys. Look for an entry like "Launchpad PPA for Kendek" in this case. Then use `apt-key del` to delete it:

  ```
   sudo apt-key del 73C62A1B
  ```

---

As mentioned in [the comments](/q/219341/219344#comment1010961_219344) by [@SeF](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/368368/sef),
you can use the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r <the repo you want to remove>
```

Comment: Note: the short key id is no longer shown when you use the `apt-key list` command, but it is actually the last 8 characters of the long key that is shown.

Comment: The command is `sudo add-apt-repository -r <the repo you want to remove>`.

Comment: I think @SeF you should make your comment an actual answer as that should be the accepted answer to this question. As a comment, albeit with high vote count, it is not given the attention it deserves.

Comment: Thanks @Timo, unfortunately no new answers are allowed for this old question.

Comment: Oh I see this has been flagged as a duplicate

Comment: Why does this have 262 likes?  It doesn't even work.

Comment: In Debian, `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` and delete the entry.  The solution mentioned above is non-working in Debian, which is an objectively far superior OS to Ubuntu.