# How to replace Php7 install from dotdeb with php7 from Stretch

Tags: debian, php, php7

I used PHP7 from the [dotdeb](https://www.dotdeb.org) packages for my install of Debian 8 Jessie. Now, I want to upgrade to Debian 9 Stretch (which has php7) and I want my Php7 package to be from Stretch and no more from dotdeb.

Is it possible, or should I keep php from dotdeb?

(Note: I don't want to uninstall php and reinstall it because I don't want to lose my configurations...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the php7 from dotdeb to the stretch package, but to avoid any conflicts it will be best to uninstalling and then reinstalling php.

Which can be achieved by:

```
apt-get remove php7.0
```

followed by removing the repository for dotdeb from `sources.list` ([see this stackexchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/219344/86219)) then update apt and install php7 again:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install php7.0
```

(package name is PHP7.0)

Comment: I'd like to avoid loosing my conf files...

Comment: by default `apt-get remove` leaves the configuration files unless you use the  `purge` command so your configs should be fine.

Comment: In fact, I have removed dotdeb link in sources.list and the update was OK witout deleting php first.