# Repository is deprecated

Tags: kali-linux

Hi i run this code in my kali linux terminal
`Sudo add-apt-repository -remove ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa`
It show this message

- !!please note that this repository is deprecated!! *
- Actually this is double deprecated and it is also then replaced *

I just want to remove this repository

I'm Using Kali Linux 2021.2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to undo sudo add-apt-repository?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60595/how-to-undo-sudo-add-apt-repository)

Comment: Kali is really not the Linux distro of choice when trying to use external Ubuntu PPAs, and especially not if you want to run windows software. Don't take it from me – Kali themselves say so! https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your command line `-remove`, use `--remove` instead:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt update
```

Manually:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list
sudo apt update
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Using `apt` command:
   `sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:[PPA_NAME]`
2. Using `purge` command:

- First, install `ppa-purge` using this command `sudo apt install ppa-purge`
- Then remove the ppa repository using `sudo ppa-purge ppa:[PPA_NAME]`

Check out this cool website for more information related to your question.
Cr: https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/ubuntu/remove-an-apt-repository-ubuntu

Comment: Also you can check out this link. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219341/how-to-apt-delete-repository

Comment: `ppa-purge` is a Ubuntu package, not Kali.